# How to enable option to save credentials in Viscosity VPN?

Tags: vpn, network

Apparently sometimes Viscosity disables the option to save credentials into Keychain and even reinstalling the application does not bring it back.

What is the trick to re-enable them?

Answer (score 3):

While Viscosity support refused to answer the question and stated that reinstallation is needed, I was able to find this trick after a bit of digging:

```
defaults write com.viscosityvpn.Viscosity KeyChainSupport YES
```